# IIS Uses code that was commented out, not the updated code in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, iis, iis-7

I updated my code in C# but am not seeing the changes executed when I run the web service. I have tried
-Rebuilding all my code
-Restarting IIS
-Clearing the cache on chrome
-Using an incognito window

What is going on? Here is an image showing it is using my commented code and not the updated code I have changed.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze2X4.jpg
[image: iisCommentedCode]

```
string query = "select * from product";
        /*
        string query = string.Format("SELECT p.GTIN " + 
            ",sc.StudyCellId " +
            ",pm.Name " +
            ",pm.Description as PricetagDescription " +
            ",pm.Size as Size " +
            ",pm.Brand as Brand " +
            ",pm.Price as Price " +
            ",pm.ProductKey as ProductKey " +
            ",pm.Category as Category " +
            ",pm.Details.value('(/Details/Tags/Tag[@Type=\"Type\"])[1]/@Name', 'varchar(max)') AS Type " +
            ",pm.Details.value('(/Details/Tags/Tag[@Type=\"Form\"])[1]/@Name', 'varchar(max)') AS Form " +
            "FROM StudyCell sc " +
            "inner join ProductMeta pm on pm.StudyCellId = sc.StudyCellId " +
            "inner join Product p on pm.ProductId = p.ProductId " +
            "where StudyId = {0} " +
            "order by sc.StudyCellId " +
            ",GTIN", studyId);
        */
```

Comment: Please post the code itself, not an image.

Comment: The image is showing in that while debugging it is using the wrong code. I will post code the snippet of code if it will help i guess

Comment: Are you building in Visual Studio? Make sure if your debugging in Visual Studio that you are not deploying to the local Visual Studio built in Web Server, and that you are deploying to IIS.

If using Visual Studio 2010 you can right-click on the project for the service, and select properties. Then select the Web tab. Under the Servers section you can configure the URL. There is also a button to create the virtual directory.

Comment: Might be a silly question but have you actually deployed the updated .dll?

Comment: Please post the entire method and/or class to make our jobs easier.

Comment: @Ramhound, I can't since it's not technically my code... plus that would be a lot of code

Comment: @user2230341 - **So come up with an example that replicates the problem**  The single line of code you provided is not enough to resolve your problem.

Comment: @Ramhound This is my first time with web services, anyways there's a service called ExportData in my controller and I even deleted it but when I call it from my website on localhost (localhost/ClientPortal/ExportData) it still runs as the first time i built it. Now i have tried to rebuild everything, deleted the DLL's, cleared the cache and still nothing.

Comment: Telling us your using `ExportData` isn't helpful considering that it isn't a default .NET class.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Well i did figure it out. I deleted all the DLL's again and rebuilt now i'm getting a different result. So what exactly was wrong? Doesnt the DLL get rebuilt every time you rebuild in visual studio?

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem before.  If I remember rightly what I had to do was delete by binaries in the bin folder then rebuild the solution.

Also strangely closing down VS and restarting helps too!

Also ensure your live app to pointing to the right binary folder. i.e it may be pointing to the Release version, and you're working on the Debug version.

HTH,
Gary